# Android adding to ArrayList replace older items and i have the same data

Tags: android

in below code i'm trying to add some data to `items`, on each adding data into `for` clause value of items have the same data, but in log cat there are different result.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();

for (int p = 0; p < allFoodBean.size(); p++) {
    if (allFoodBean.get(p).getItemId().equals("food1")) {
        item.put("id", allFoodBean.get(p).getId());
        item.put("name", allFoodBean.get(p).getName());
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

problem is adding data to `items` in this line of code: `items.add(item);`
how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Can u post your  allFoodBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move item initialization inside the for loop.

Having it initialized outside will keep on adding food beans in for-loop to same item `Map` instance and finally you would have a single `Map` item in items `ArrayList` instead of having multiple `Map` objects inside the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<>();

for (int p = 0; p < allFoodBean.size(); p++) {
    if (allFoodBean.get(p).getItemId().equals("food1")) {
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("id", allFoodBean.get(p).getId());
        item.put("name", allFoodBean.get(p).getName());
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, problem resolved, please let me to accept your post

Comment: yes sure, but i have to wait some minute to SF let me to accept that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> item = null;

for (int p = 0; p < allFoodBean.size(); p++) {
    if (allFoodBean.get(p).getItemId().equals("food1")) {
        item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("id", allFoodBean.get(p).getId());
        item.put("name", allFoodBean.get(p).getName());
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

When ever if condition becomes false create `new HashMap<>()`